# How do I switch between Haxe 2 and 3 on a MAC (and back)

Tags: macos, haxe

I currently have two projects using Haxe, one in Haxe 2 and the new one in Haxe 3.
Can anyone explain to me how to switch between using Haxe 3/2 on a MAC? Currently I'm stuck on 3 and can't work on my older project! :(

Thanks!

Comment: It's should not be so hard to upgrade your project to Haxe 3.
I think there is no sense of using obsolete Haxe 2. If you getting some errors, post here, and I will try to help you to port it to Haxe 3.

Answer (score 0):

These installs can be a problem, but everything is OK if you use symlink!

You can find a script here on how to [Install multiple Haxe versions](https://gist.github.com/JbIPS/5590277) and one to [switch between version](https://gist.github.com/JbIPS/5597917).

Basically, it create a folder for each version of Haxe and a symbolic link in `/usr/lib/haxe` that point to the current installation. This way, you can safely switch between any number of versions.

Tell me if you got some errors using theses scripts, so I can upgrade them.

Comment: install-haxe-osx: line 2: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
install-haxe-osx: line 2: syntax error near `;'
install-haxe-osx: line 2: `if [[ -z $1]]; then'

Comment: How did you run the script ? What's your version of Bash ?

Answer (score 0):

i ran into similar problems ...

finally i ended up making a swapHaxe.sh  where i rename haxe & neko to _haxe _neko then rename *haxe* & *neko* to haxe § neko.
i just have to type sudo swapHaxe and it goes fine ...